# I am attempting to recreate a circuit for a PWM, to control a 6v dc motor's speed

Tags: circuit-analysis, dc, pwm

I am using a breadboard and am attempting to recreate the circuit from this [post](https://howtomechatronics.com/how-it-works/electronics/how-to-make-pwm-dc-motor-speed-controller-using-555-timer-ic/). From the post I am using this image

[image: Circuit Illustration]

As the circuit for recreating it. However, I am not getting the results I would expect. On the motor terminals I would expect one of them to be ground (however I am but a simplton) but both are producing voltages. One is producing 9v and the other 7v.

If you feel it would be helpful I can upload some images of the breadboard setup, but Im not sure how visibile everything will be in an image. I have grounded both caps (c1, c2) but as it doesnt show any other groundings maybe I have missed something?

Comment: there is a schematic diagram in that article ... follow that instead  ... https://howtomechatronics.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/PWM-DC-Motor-Speed-Control-with-555-Timer-IC.png

Comment: the motor is not connected directly to ground ... there is a switch (transistor) between the motor and ground

Comment: @jsotola ar you suggesting the terminal on the TIP that doesnt have anything on it should be GND?

Comment: Thank you for the help, your questions prompted me to look at the schematic again and reliased the pin outputs are on there and i missed grounded ping 1! Thanks, all working now

Comment: all three terminals on the TIP show being connected

Comment: Yes as I was using the PCB layout instead of the Schematic I missed that. (I noob)

Comment: ex noob now ...

Answer (score 0):

Please show the schematic.

From the PCB I can see that one terminal of the motor is connected to the +VE power input (not ground). The transistor Q1 then connects the other terminal to ground with the PWM signal. It basically looks ok.

Comment: I am clearly not understanding this and I assume I must have done something wrong as the motor doesnt seem to get powered. I assumed V+ was positive voltage as in the positive terminal from source.

Comment: I dont see a schematic on the post, the only ones I can see inculde the internal structure of the 555.

Comment: I have just GNDed the terminal on the TIP (which has no connections on the image in the post). This has now brought the motor to life but the POT doesnt seem to vary its speed.

Comment: Got it!, seems I hadnt grounded pin 1 on the 555!